# HTML video showing black screen but sound is playing on iOS 15

Tags: html, css, ios, video

My website shows a video using video tag which worked perfectly until not long ago.
The video is working but when pressing on full screen, the video is playing but the screen is black while the sound is still playing. The issue occurs only on iPhones with iOS 15 (using Safari and Chrome also).
Things I've tried:

- I've tried playing the video directly with a URL to the actual file(to check its not codec issue) and it worked properly.
- My video tag has 'position: absolute;' on it and I tried removing it(even though it breaks my layout) and that didn't work either.
- Tried pausing the video immediately and playing it after the video loads.
- Tried applying a background: white; or any non-transparent color to the video tag.
- Tried removing auto play.
- Tried to disable 'GPU process: Media' on safari settings just to check if that affects anything
  and it didnt.

This is the html:

```
       <video data-test-id="long-video" #longVideo muted controls playsinline [class.d-none]="!isShortVideoHidden"
        *ngIf="isPageLoaded" src="https://cdn1.someurl.com/videos/commercial_1.mp4"
        type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

and the css(with the parent):

```
@media only screen and(min-width:992px) {
.fixed-video {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: 0.4s;

    video {
        width: 80%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

}

Please tell me if you have struggled with this and know how to solve it.
Thank you :)

Comment: I had something similar where the audio playing and no picture at all, the video codec was `H.265` , I convert it to `H.264` and it worked. check your video codec and if it's the same problem, convert it using any tool.

Comment: First , I mentioned that I tried playing the video directly from the URL and it worked fine. Also the video is already h.264

Comment: I'm sorry I might have misunderstood you `"and it didn't work."` this what you said.

Comment: you're right I edited it . thanks

Comment: Help Someone? Still struggling